# Install problem on Linux Mint 12

Tags: ros, rosdep, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking for some guidance on a very unhelpful error message.  I am trying to perform a full desktop install from source for ROS on a machine running Linux Mint 12 using the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source.  For this machine, "uname -a" gives: **Linux mobile 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**.

I have used the sections that are specific to Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric), on which Mint 12 appears to be based, but I run into an error when running rosinstall (rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no").  It appears as if this is somewhere in some Python code (which I have no familiarity with) and the actual message is **KeyError: '12'**.  The raw output is as follows (sorry for the formatting, can't quite work out how to handle line breaks and angle brackets in Markdown):

`Bootstrapping ROS build Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too. [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros', 'ros_comm'] [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/bd/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120219-112427 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros', 'ros_comm'] to: ['test_rosdep', 'test_rosmake', 'test_rospack', 'test_roslib', 'test_roscreate', 'rosboost_cfg', 'rosemacs', 'rosbash', 'rosclean', 'rospack', 'rosmake', 'rosunit', 'rosdep', 'roscreate', 'roslib', 'rosbuild', 'roslang', 'mk', 'std_srvs', 'std_msgs', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_roswtf', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_ros', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_rospy', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_rostopic', 'test_rosservice', 'test_crosspackage', 'test_rosbag', 'perf_roscpp', 'test_rostest', 'test_rostime', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_roscpp', 'test_rosparam', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_rosnode', 'rosmaster', 'rosparam', 'rosgraph', 'rosnode', 'rosconsole', 'topic_tools', 'rosservice', 'rosbag', 'rosbagmigration', 'roslaunch', 'rostopic', 'rosmsg', 'rosout', 'rostest', 'cpp_common', 'roswtf', 'xmlrpcpp', 'rostime', 'message_filters', 'roscore_migration_rules', 'roslisp', 'rospy', 'roscpp_traits', 'roscpp', 'roscpp_serialization'] [ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . . Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/bd/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module> if rma.main(): File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__ self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 535, in __init__ self.detect_os() File "/home/bd/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 554, in detect_os self._os_version = os_class.get_version() File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 133, in get_version return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()] KeyError: '12' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/bd/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module> if rma.main(): File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__ self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list) File "/home/bd/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 535, in __init__ self.detect_os() File "/home/bd/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 554, in detect_os self._os_version = os_class.get_version() File "/home/bd/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 133, in get_version return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()] KeyError: '12' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module> pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.30', 'rosinstall') File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 781, in <module> sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 771, in rosinstall_main subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(options.path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash') File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /home/bd/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27905/install-problem-on-linux-mint-12/) by [bd.at.rivenhill](https://answers.ros.org/users/1812/bd.at.rivenhill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was caused by missing entries in ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py and core.py (as noted in a previous answer).  Note that the debian.py mapping in self.version_map for the Mint class appears to have changed from using version numbers to code names as of Ubuntu 11.10/Mint 12.  See my patch at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3858 for details.

---

Originally posted by [bd.at.rivenhill](https://answers.ros.org/users/1812/bd.at.rivenhill/) with karma: 46 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try add your OS in row

```
rep111version_map = {'lucid':'10.04', 'maverick':'10.10', 'natty':'11.04'}
```

in file "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py"

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bd.at.rivenhill](https://answers.ros.org/users/1812/bd.at.rivenhill/) on 2012-02-19**:
Helpful, but not the solution see my ticket for details: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3858